# send email if data lasts more than 12 hours in a table, SQL

Tags: sql

I need to write a sql to find out if a data(transactions) lasts more than 12 hours in a particular table

Comment: use getdate() while inserting records. Create a job that checks if data lasts more than 12 hours, it would send an email.

Comment: Please visit help center, take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and How to Ask. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducile](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example of your attempt, input and expected output.

Comment: Please specify which database. Does your table have a column to identify load timestamp ?

Answer (score 0):

Every data entry can be logged with timestamps using GETDATE() or with Triggers.
Create a service to check if data lasts more than 12 hours and if data obtained, Create a mail service to send mails.

For simple SQL query to get obtain data >= 12 hours, use DATE_SUB or DATEDIFF accordingly. Example below:

```
select count(*) as c
from  data
where dateCreated >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR);
```

Comment: Did it help you? if so, consider accepting answer. if you have other query, post as seperate question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

Use below query. This query gives last 12 hours data.

```
 If exists ( select  1 from table_name
 where column_name >= dateadd(hour, -12 , getdate()))
 begin

    -- Write script for send email
 end
```

Comment: i am using only " If exists ( select  1 from table_name
 where column_name >= dateadd(hour, -12 , getdate())) " we have an intel agent to send email, but that query is giving syntax error